# Ksoap exception in j2me

Tags: java-me, ksoap, gzipstream

I am create one J2ME application which call to .NET WCF web service and me used ksoap.
I am using netbeans IDE.
But when I run that application then gives run time exception is

```null
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Invalid stream or encoding: java.io.IOException: Error in GZIP header, first byte doesn't match (position:START_DOCUMENT null@0:0) caused by: java.io.IOException: Error in GZIP header, first byte doesn't match
```

What is the reason for that exception?

Here compile time that is no any error.

Comment: thx gnat..  But I code same as some trusted web site gives then why this exception come?